# Bytes per row and/or column

Tags: database, vertica

How can I determine the bytes per row and/or column for a specific schema.table in Vertica?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the following system table: column_storage

It has all the information you need. Row count and bytes per projection per node. You can always query it using SUM() to get the cut you want.